# How can I mute Kinect's mic without leaving my game?

Tags: kinect, xbox-one

For the Xbox One, how do we mute the Kinect's mic while in game chat without leaving the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not!

However, people are petitioning to get it in one of the next updates. See [Player Feedback](http://playerfeedback.net/xbox/) for more information in the voice Commands section.

Answer (score -1):

pause the game, go to settings, then Kinect and mute game.

quicker command is `xbox go to settings`

then return to game.